# What is tissue gel?

Tags: lymphatic-system

My book consists of following lines."The interstitial fluid is entrapped in minute space among proteoglycan filaments. This combination of proteoglycan filaments and the fluid entrapped within them has a characteristic of gel so called tissue gel.  Instead of flowing interstitial fluid mainly diffuses through gel.  This diffuion allows rapid transport of interstitium of water nutrients,oxygen,cell excreta e.t.c.
I can't get the meaning of these lines.  I tried to search on net but didn't get a satisfactory explanation.  Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the question, "**tissue gel**" clearly refers to "[proteoglycan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteoglycan) filaments and the fluid entrapped within them" and which appears in the interstitial space.

This is the same as what the Wikipedia article says about [Extracellular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracellular_matrix):

> **Gels** of polysaccharides and fibrous proteins fill the interstitial space and act as a compression buffer against the stress placed on the
>   ECM. *(Source: Essential cell biology, 2004)*

[A.C, Guyton et al from University of Mississippi School of Medicine, 1973](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-3228-2_11) also says the same:

> Though 1/6 of most tissues is composed of interstitial fluid, this
>   fluid is generally held tightly in place in the form of a **gel.** The
>   reticulum of this gel is composed mainly of hyaluronic acid, but this
>   is cross-linked slightly with collagen fibers to form a meshwork in
>   which the interstitial fluids are trapped. The presence of this gel
>   reduces the mobility of fluid in the tissues...

The exact term ["tissue gel"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=918&ei=4-SVXfTtAszLwAKIhYmgCA&q=site%3Agov%20%22tissue%20gel%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22tissue%20gel%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9216.12625..13341...0.2..0.108.577.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30.eekS4Lvs-kU&ved=0ahUKEwi066Weh4DlAhXMJVAKHYhCAoQQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) is very rarely used in biology or histology, though.

You are probably confused because of this sentence, which is messed up: "This diffusion allows rapid transport <strike>of interstitium</strike> of water, nutrients, oxygen, cell excreta e.t.c. " It should be: "This diffusion allows rapid transport of water nutrients, oxygen, cell excreta e.t.c. through the interstitium."